# What is the mount point Samsung Galaxy S for Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, android

What will be the mount point for Samsung Galaxy S cell phone, when I connect it to a Ubuntu Desktop? It doesn't mount automatically

From `/var/log/messages`, I can only see this

```
Jul 23 23:49:11 carfield kernel: [1461671.160016] usb 1-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 26
Jul 23 23:49:12 carfield kernel: [1461671.454357] usb 1-6: configuration #4 chosen from 1 choice
Jul 23 23:49:12 carfield kernel: [1461671.522077] cdc_acm 1-6:4.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Any idea?

Comment: .​.​. W​h​a​t​?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually mounting the phone in USB mass storage mode are you? When you plug the Galaxy into USB you should get a menu up on the phone's screen asking which mode to attach in, you probably want to select Mass Storage, you then need to select the USB Connected item in the notification area, and select "Mount". Unless you've done both of those bits it won't mount it's drive to any PC OS.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting the phone to your system, it should appear on your desktop on under the Places menu. Click on it, Nautilus should open to the place where it is mounted. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and that should show the mount point.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't, added more detail at the post

Comment: The phone seems to be getting detected only as a Modem, not as a mass storage device. Is there somewhere in phone where you can switch modes ?

Comment: Then what is the mount point? BTW, is that mean I cannot copy files using USB but have to be network??

Answer (score 1):

In the Galaxy S running Android 2.1,  you must put the USB into debug mode. Use 
*Applications » Settings » Applications » Development* and select *USB debugging*.

Then when you connect your phone to Ubuntu with the USB cable, it will be mounted as USB storage devices.

You can find the mount points by monitoring the syslog file. I use `tail` as follows. On the Linux side in a terminal window type:

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` (you may need to do this as well)

`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog.`

The other way is to down load QuickSSHd from the Google Play Store and then just SFTP to your phone from your Ubuntu computer using a WIFI connection.